# Non-Interactive input

Tags: bash, aws

I am trying to run a bash script which downloads and runs another script.  The second script contains questions that must be answered by input.  I have already attempted to use expect but it fails because the downloaded script runs in bash so it will not spawn the script.

Is there another way to pass input to the script after it downloads and runs?

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/.aws
echo "[default]" >> ~/.aws/credentials
echo "aws_access_key_id = <key here>" >> ~/.aws/credentials
echo "aws_secret_access_key = <key here>" >> ~/.aws/credentials
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -o LinuxConfigurationScript.sh
chmod +x LinuxConfigurationScript.sh
./LinuxConfigurationScript.sh -r us-east-1
```

Comment: Would it be feasible to modify the LinuxConfigurationScript.sh with whatever values you need, and remove the input directives, before executing? I'm assuming that you want to automate this, and that the answers aren't simply "yes". Otherwise, you could just do `yes | LinuxConfigurationScript.sh -r us-east-1`.

Comment: That could be a thought but I'm not the keeper of the script that's being downloaded and things can change in that script at anytime.  You would be correct in that I want to automate this process.  The script asks for AWS credentials along with several other questions around region of deployment and configuration of the install.  For short, the input could be a number of things required but they would be static for each deployment I need to run.

Comment: I was thinking about using something like downloading the script once, and then downloading the copy from your own, modified source later. Other than `expect`, I'm not certain of another such tool. If I'm automating something, though, I would rather have a single, stable file than downloading a script that may have changed, anyway.

Comment: Have you considered using the `--non-interactive` option that appears to be available for that script? Also, the downloaded script is python, not bash.

Comment: @jordanm, I stand corrected, yes it is Python.  I have attempted the non-interactive script with no success.                                   root@77889ca764d0:/# ./LinuxConfigurationScript.sh -n -r us-east-1
ERROR: Missing required arguments. Please run with --help for details.

Comment: @danny the error message indicates you need to specify additional arguments with `--non-interactive`. Have you viewed the help output?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
./LinuxConfigurationScript.sh -r us-east-1 <<EOF
command 1
command 2
EOF
```

---

Ok let's do a full example:

Here is my first script `test.sh` who ask several questions (your `LinuxConfigurationScript.sh` equivalent)

```
read -p "Question 1?" ans
echo $ans
read -p "Question 2?" ans
echo $ans
read -p "Question 3?" ans
echo $ans
read -p "Question 4?" ans
echo $ans
```

Here is my second script `test2.sh` who call the first one and answer all questions:

```
./test.sh <<EOF
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 4
EOF
```

And the alternative in one line:

```
{ echo "answer 1"; echo "answer 2"; echo "answer 3"; echo "answer 4"; } | ./test.sh
```

Comment: thanks for the answer though this didn't work for me.  I instead used a bash script which called on the expect script.  Not ideal but it works.